# Error SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: mysql

I do not know what I am doing wrong here. When the following query is executed I receive the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens

This is my query :

```
SELECT id, recipe_name, ingredients, directions, user_id, category_id, country_id, name, type, size FROM recipes WHERE user_id =:user_id LIMIT:per_page OFFSET:pagination_offset
```

And here is the script:

```
$page = !empty($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$per_page = 3;

$total_count = $this->countAll($iId); // which is 9 at this point

$pagination = new Pagination($page, $per_page, $total_count);

$pagination_offset = $pagination->offset(); 


$sWhereClause = "WHERE user_id =:user_id ";
$sLimitClause = "LIMIT:per_page ";
$sOffsetClause = "OFFSET:pagination_offset " ;

$aBinding = array (
    ':user_id' => $iUserId,
    ':per_page' => (int)$per_page,
    ':pagination_offset' => (int)$pagination_offset,
);



$sql = " 
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                recipes
            " . $sWhereClause . "
            " . $sLimitClause . "
            " . $sOffsetClause . "
        ";

try{

        $var = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $var->execute($binding);

        return $var->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch (Exception $ex) {

        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You define your bindings in the array `$aBinding`, but then send `$binding` to `execute`. Just use the same variable consistently, and you should be fine:

```
$var->execute($aBinding);
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that PHP warns you about these kind of typos if you configure it properly.